# Django ModelForm with Multilingual

Tags: django

I have defined model as like below

```
class UserType(models.Model):

    user_type_id        = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_type_name_en   = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    user_type_name_de   = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    user_type_name_fr   = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    status              = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user_type_name_en

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'usertype'

class User(models.Model):

    user_id             = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    email_id            = models.EmailField( blank=False, null=False)
    user_type           = models.ForeignKey(UserType )
```

I have create ModelForm for 'User' and hooked with a Form which works perfect. As per my above code I always get 'user_type_name_en' in my drop down (foreign key mapping). I want to dynamically change the field based on the language option. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Django way to make your site multilingual: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

You can do something like:

```
from django.conf import settings

...

def __unicode__(self):
    return getattr(self, "user_type_name_%s" % settings.LANGUAGE_CODE, self.user_type_name_en)
```